# Why does this code cause error while using form tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote JavaScript code to show the particular div tag in textbox by onclick event.

If I use a form tag, it's not showing div tag id in textfield by onclick. If I remove the form tag, it works fine. Why?

Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MMID(clicked_id) {
    document.getElementById('MMID').value = clicked_id;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="28" onclick="MMID(this.id)">Hello Ram</div>
    <input name="MMID" type="text" id="MMID" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code :

```
<div id="28" class="mycls">Hello Ram</div>

$('.mycls').click(function(){
    clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#MMID').val(clicked_id);
});
```

You need to load jquery on your page for use above code, but its very simple.

Let me know if any query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Function name and id name should be changed.Check console it will give you an error.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function MMID_FUNC(clicked_id)
 {
   document.getElementById('MMID').value=clicked_id;

 }
</script>

<div id="28" onclick="MMID_FUNC(this.id)">Hello Ram</div>
   <input name="MMID" type="text" id="MMID" />
```

Comment: not showing any error.if i use form tag,onclick functionality not working.if i remove form tag working fine

Comment: @user3128717 no problem.If issue is resolved then mark answer as correct.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MMID(clicked_id)
{
document.getElementById('MMID').value=clicked_id;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<div id="28" onclick="javasxcript: MMID(this.innerHTML)">Hello Ram</div>
<input name="MMID" type="text" id="MMID" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="28" onClick="MMID(this);">Hello Ram</div>
<input name="MMID" type="text" id="MMID" />
```

Javascript:

```
function MMID(ele)
{
  document.getElementById('MMID').value= ele.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mmid(clicked_id) {
            document.getElementById('MMID').value = clicked_id;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="28" onclick="mmid(this.id)">Hello Ram</div>
    <input name="MMID" type="text" id="MMID" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the same name for your function and div id in a form tag.
Javascript thinks that the MMID is an object, and not a function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function gets(clicked_id)
            {
                document.getElementById('MMID').value=clicked_id;

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="tests.php" method="post">
            <div id="28" onclick="gets(this.id)">Hello Ram</div>
            <input name="MMID" type="text" id="MMID" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```